# i get data from API as result as jpeg , but i dont know how to turn it into imageView

Tags: api, kotlin, retrofit2, dagger-hilt

I used Kotlin , retrofit, MVVM, I  usually get data image from API as Web URL image, this time I get jpeg . I don't know how to convert them into image view, and usually I  using glide as opener. Hope that you can help.

This is my API looks like:

[image]

Comment: That is not a `jpeg`. That is a `String`, which represents a path in some storage, which means nothing. Unless you already have the image in your assets and you can map it to that asset, you can't do anything. If there is any space for speculation, the backend sends you the image location on their storage.

Comment: which means , i need to ask the backend to re type the datatype right?

Comment: If the BE wants to send you a `String` as an encoded image, they can; if they want to send you a URL, it would still be a `String`. You don't need another type, you need a value that you can do something with it.